# What does the {0} in this oracle query mean " select ... from STAFFSV {0} order by SEQID"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have to convert this query to SQL Server:

```
Select SEQID AS ID, USERNAME AS USERID, FIRSTNAME + ' ' + LASTNAME AS NAME, CASE CONSULTANT WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END CONS, CASE ASSIGN WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS ASSIGN, CASE PRINT WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS PRINT, CASE SHIPPING WHEN 1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END AS SHIP, ACTIVE from STAFFSV {0} order by SEQID
```

But I don't understand what the {0} would be converted to in SQL Server

Comment: Please consider the people trying to read your SQL, and update your question to add the _formatted_ code.

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with SQL or Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the full query. `{0}` is a placeholder for another section of the query (probably a WHERE clause) that will be filled in by an application

Comment: Yeah, `{0}` is the common placeholder for the C#/.Net `String.Format()` function. This would not be valid T-SQL, especially because curly braces are often used by ODBC or JDBC providers for their internal functions.

Comment: I added the entire query. I didn't realize by shortening the query it was not a legal sql statement

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what the {0} does in the query

Comment: @JohnO'Neil It doesn't do anything, because it's not actually part of the query. It's a **placeholder** the client program will use to substitute in additional sections.